# Any way to disable tooltip (title attribute) when right click (contextmenu)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip, contextmenu, title

Using jQuery, I would like the tooltip to work on hover, and context menu to work on right click, but not with the tooltip hovering over my contextmenu. Is this possible?

Comment: I'm using the right click plugin from here: http://abeautifulsite.net/blog/2008/05/jquery-right-click-plugin/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[What about something like this?](http://jsfiddle.net/3dLW3/)

Basically, blank the `title` attribute on context menu initialization, and then reset it on context menu disappearing.

Comment: ye... there is always a delay before the tooltip sitting on the context meny goes away (since hover always kicks in before any clicking)... I'm trying my luck here... not sure if there is a elegant solution.

Comment: @Brandon What browser are you using? I just tested it with Firefox 3.6 and the tooltip instantly disappeared when the context menu was invoked.

Comment: by golly you are right! works in Safari and FF but not IE. This was my initial solution... but of course unfortunately IE takes up the highest number of users by %.

Comment: will give it a few days, if someone knows a way for IE.

Comment: Answer is not possible in IE.

Answer (score 0):

I think you will be lucky to override control of the tooltip display away from Internet Explorer;

However, try this:

1. Set the title attribute to an empty string on hover, storing the
   value in a custom attribute.
2. Then draw the tooltip yourself
   using javascript/dom manipulation.

Right clicking could then vanquish the tooltip.